# How do I compare Python list with Postgres Array in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a column in my PSQL table type array of type integers, let's call the column `tags`.I have a Python list that has type integers, lets' call it `categories`.

How do I run a SQLAlchemy query so that I return any row in my table if the tags column has one or more matching integers to the categories array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `in_` as documented [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators). In their example

> query.filter(User.name.in_(['ed', 'wendy', 'jack']))

the list `['ed, 'wendy', 'jack']` are your `categories` and instead of `User.name` you use your table and the `tags` column.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the list of `categories` is not very large, this is one way how to go about it using an `OR` of `any(...)` for each category:

```
q = db.session.query(MyTable)
clauses = [MyTable.tags.any(cat_id) for cat_id in categories]
q = q.filter(db.or_(*clauses))
for r in q.all():
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Approaching an identical problem, I found the in_ operator (marked as answer) not to work: I got a "malformed ARRAY literal" error (note: the the example given filters on a column of type String, not of type ARRAY)
@van originated the approach that worked for me. However, the db object in my case does not have an or_ attribute. To get it to work I simply imported or_ directly from SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
# ...
q = db.session.query(MyTable)
clauses = [MyTable.tags.any(cat_id) for cat_id in categories]
q = q.filter(or_(*clauses))
for r in q.all():
    print(r)
```

Upvotes belong to @van (I'd have commented on his, but don't have the reputation - sorry van).

Comment: Hi. If you don't have reputation, you should work to earn it. Posting comments as answers brings the quality of the website down, so you should avoid it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Cthulhu, I understand how the site works.
Nevertheless the answer (which I took 15+ minutes out of my day to find and verify thoroughly) contributes something that will hopefully save others that time. I felt it worth adding, I hope you agree.