# SQLAlchemy: Is it possible to combine "like" and "in" within the same query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-like, sql-in

I have the following SQLAlchemy query working

```
incomplete_list = ['a','b','c']

complete_units = []
for elem in incomplete_list:
    query = Table.query.filter(Table.name.like(elem))
    for row in query:
        complete_units.append(row.unit_number)
```

I would like to avoid using for loop to query the database multiple times. Would it be possible to combine "in" and "like" operators so that I only query the database once? Or is there a better way of doing this query? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561075/how-do-i-compare-python-list-with-postgres-array-in-sqlalchemy):*

```
incomplete_list = ['a','b','c']
complete_units = []

clauses = [Table.name.like(elem) for elem in incomplete_list]
query = Table.query.filter(or_(*clauses))
complete_units = query.all()
```

Strictly speaking the result of this execution path might be different from you sample code because if the `Table` contains rows which would satisfy multiple criteria from the `incomplete_list`, your sample code will return the same row multiple times, whereas this code will do it only once (which I believe is desired).

Comment: Would it be possible to return the result of the query in the same order as the incomplete_list?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420720/99594

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Alchemy, its useful to consider what SQL you want before thinking about the python. You're trying to get the unit numbers of any row where a certain column matches any of a certain pattern.

```
SELECT unit_number FROM Table WHERE name like any ("pattern1", "pattern2")
```

SQL Alchemy does that like this-

```
q = select(Table.c.unit_number).where(Table.c.name.like(any_(incomplete_list)))
complete_unites = [row[0] for row in conn.execute(q)]
```

To elaborate a bit more...

The way you wrote your code `Table.query.filter(Table.name.like(elem))` You were executing a separate SQL query for each loop. While that may be okay, it means that each one is independent and you couldn't do things like ordering with the DB if you chose to do so.

Also, the syntax you shared is probably `flask-sqlalchemy`. The syntax I used is the 1.4 version, but can easily be adapted. Flask-sqlalchemy uses the ORM model, and it adds a special property to each class that is basically

```
class Model:
  @property
  def query(self):
    return Session.Query(Model)
```

The problem being, there is no easy way to select specific rows or columns, but its hardly the end of the world (you just return more data than you need, whether that matters is up to you)

```
q = Table.query.filter(Table.name.like(any_(incomplete_list)))
complete_units = [row.unit_number for row in q.all()]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to return the result of the query in the same order as the incomplete_list?